# Evaluation with ground truth label and list of predicted labels

Tags: python-3.x, statistics, precision-recall

Currently, I am trying to predict the top five/10 subjects to a statistics exercise based on the exercise's description. The subjects and exercises (with ground truth label, as integer) are provided in CSV format. The ground truth label is also present in the subjects' CSV, and is there called "id".

My current model produces a tuple for ever exercise, of which the first element is the ground truth label, the second element is a list of the predicted labels.

Then my question: how to compute (Accuracy,) Precision, Recall, and F1 (if possible also MRR and MAR)?

Also, all exercises and subject are converted to vectors. Furthermore, I calculate accuracy by counting all instances for which the ground truth is present in the top 5/10, and dividing this the total number of exercises.

*note: in the code exercise = question, and subject = kc

My variables are as follows:

```
question_data = df[['all_text_clean', 'all_text_as_vector', 'groud_truth_id'] ].values

kc_data = subject_df[['id', 'all_text_as_vector']].values
```

Then, I loop over every exercise-question pair:

```
question_candidates = []

for qtext, qvec, gt_id in question_data:

    scores = []

    for kc_id, kc_vec in kc_data:
        score = distance.cosine(qvec, kc_vec) # calculate cosine similarities

        scores.append((kc_id, score)) # kc_id and related store cos-sim

    scores = sorted(scores, key=itemgetter(1)) # sort cos-sims and related ids

    candites = [id for id, score in scores][:5] # only id is relevant. These are the suggestions

    question_candidates.append((gt_id, candites))
```

Accuracy is moderate: around 0,59. I don't expect anything higher since this is just a baseline model.